# When building with webpack typescript types seem to be undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-4

Building my `React` application using `Typescript` with `Webpack 4` builds successfully. But when trying to view the application in the browser, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'USER' of undefined

The property is from a Typescript enum.
The application runs fine with the dev build.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: I can add code, but what code do you want to see? The prod config? The type definitions? If it works locally (yarn start) but not with a build (yarn build), what would be better for you to see?

Comment: Let's start with the definition of the enum, the line of the code that is accessing the enum, and any exports and imports used to make the enum available to the code that is accessing it.  Be sure to state the names of all files involved.  Your `tsconfig.json` and Webpack configuration may also be helpful.